# Set display of Literal based on another Literal value

Tags: asp.net

What is the best way to set a literal text block to only display when another literal text block has returned a value?

Here is the code I am trying to build, with comments where the logic would go.

```
<!-- Will be shown if there is content in the DB -->
<asp:Literal id="letter_to_zelda" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

<!-- Will be also shown if there is content in the db, but 
     I only want to show it if the line above had no content to display -->
<asp:Literal id="letter_to_link" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign these values after you retrieve values from the database in code behind.

```
letter_to_zelda.Text = ValueFromDb;
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ValueFromDb))
{
    //if content is not static, assign it
    letter_to_link.Text = LetterText;
    letter_to_link.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that code Pascal. Unfortunately, the C code is inaccessible in this scenario. Do you know of a way to accomplish this within .aspx file?

Comment: You can write code in the aspx too, but how and where are you fetching from the database?

Comment: The aspx file is an email template that is pulling content from a SQL DB based on certain criteria that the user meets. Unfortunately, the aspx is not very smart and is displaying multiple blocks of content form the DB. I am hoping to get the aspx to not display the second block if the first block has content.

Comment: I do not really understand the templating used, but you embed c# code in an aspx by putting it between `<%` and `%>`

Comment: Thank you very much Pascal, I will post back with results :)